Why would using runOnUIThread give me more ANRs than runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main)?
I have some code that can mostly run on a worker thread but one single line must run on the UI thread.
So I used to have this code that gave a lot of ANRs.
methodOnWorkerThread(){
    ..some calls...
    runOnUIThread{
        ..some more calls...
        callThatRequiresTheUIThreadAndGivesANRs()
    }
}

I changed that code to be:
methodOnWorkerThread(){
    ..some calls...
    ..some more calls...
    runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) {
        callThatRequiresTheUIThreadAndGivesANRs()
    }
}

And with that all my ANRs went away.
I realize ..some more calls... could be the culprit but all the ANR stack traces had callThatRequiresTheUIThreadAndGivesANRs().
So is there a difference as far as ANRs are concerned between runOnUIThread and runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main)?
Edit: I should have mentioned, I don't see the ANRs myself, I only get them on firebase or the Play Store console once released.

Can you try moving "some more calls" and see if the results are different. Ideally both the above codes should give you an ANR

Unfortunately I have to make releases to test this as I've never seen the ANRs myself.

As a rule of thumb, nothing other than UI related manipulation should run on the main thread


So is there a difference as far as ANRs are concerned between runOnUIThread and runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main)?

Those two are not equivalent.
runOnUIThread() is equivalent to runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main.immediate). Both say "if we are on the main application thread right now, execute this code immediately — otherwise, enqueue the work to be done by the main application thread shortly".
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) is equivalent to post() on View or Handler. Both say "enqueue the work to be done by the main application thread shortly, regardless of what the current thread is".
For code on a worker thread, I would not expect a significant difference. However, if methodOnWorkerThread() happens to be called on the main application thread in some circumstances by accident, then the difference in behavior could contribute to ANRs.

That makes sense. Some of the calls for methodOnWorkerThread were probably made on the UI thread. So as far as ANRs go, if two blocks of code are broken up by a post() to the UI thread, does that mean they count as separate spans of time for ANRs?

@casolorz: "does that mean they count as separate spans of time for ANRs?" -- yes, insofar as control will need to have returned to the framework from the first post()'s Runnable before the second post()'s Runnable will be executed.
